# ssh is no longer using ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh

I cannot ssh anything I was able to. After a little digging I found out that it's not reading ssh config from my home directory.

```
$ ssh -xvvv server
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
(...)
```

When on an identical computer of a friend, where everything works it looks like this:

```
$ ssh -xvvv server
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kuba/.ssh/config
(...)
```

It worked earlier and I am not aware of anything I could have done to cause this problem. How could this happen, and how to fix it?

In documentation link pointed by tike it states that

> Because of the potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.

My permissions are:

```
$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 80
drwx------+ 42 kuba  1029   1428 Jul  1 16:33 ..
-rwx------   1 kuba  1029   1528 May 15 13:07 config
(...)
```

I think the problem might be with a confusion about home directory. When I force the local config file it starts to work, and then suddenly starts reading from `/nas/kuba`

```
$ ssh -xvvvF ~/.ssh/config server
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/kuba/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/kuba/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/kuba/.ssh/config line 39: Applying options for bio
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXXX [YYYY.YYY.YYY.YYY] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /nas/kuba/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

But my home dir seems to be set ok:

```
$ cd ~; pwd
/Users/kuba
$ echo $HOME
/Users/kuba
```

Comment: I was able to workaround a problem. I copied contents of ~/.ssh to /nas/kuba/.ssh. So it's actually problem with ssh suddenly using the wrong home directory, which is probably not really an ssh problem.

Comment: That last comment would be very useful information to edit into the question.

Comment: Your output indicates you are using DSA. I would find a way to switch to RSA, as it is the best/newest & I believe DSA is broken.

Comment: @trysis As far as I know, DSA is not exactly broken. However DSA is extremely sensitive to the quality of your PRNG. RSA is more robust in that respect. So I too avoid DSA keys.

Comment: @Kuba As far as I can tell `ssh` ignores the `HOME` environment variable. It is bad practice to ignore `HOME`, it seems that is what `ssh` does. If it does not use `HOME`, the only alternative I am aware of is to look it up from the `uid`. If you have two entries in `/etc/passwd` with identical `uid`, then both would end up using the same `.ssh/config` file even if they had different home.

Comment: I had the same problem. Renaming `~/.ssh/conf` to `~/.ssh/config` fixed it.

Comment: @kasperd, that should be an answer.  It's the only breadcrumb on this page that helped with *my* situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You seem to be trapped between user specific vs global ssh_config.

Please check the permission settings of your user's configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`) and your system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) to understand in more details.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ssh_config.5.html). Practically, all files under your user based `.ssh` directory should be on 600, and the `config` file should be on 644. You can set this with the following commands in your home directory:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* 
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: So I understand from the doc that it first should read config from my home directory, and later from the global (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) The question is - why is it ommitting my local config?

Comment: updated answer above

Comment: I tried. Nothing changed. I updated my quetsion with more details.

Comment: if you havent changed above question drastically while editing: 
debug1: /Users/kuba/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/kuba/.ssh/config line 39: Applying options for bio

its reading config, and your configuration wildcard seem to be playing role. I would keep simple config file to test first with defined port and dest server.

Comment: Actually I changed the question drastically to the point that I should probably close it. It seems that ssh is treating other directory as my home folder. Something that's neither ~, nor $HOME.

Comment: I had to chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config because of a permssions are too open error, after that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

check permissions

```
ls -lsd ~/.ssh
```

and

```
ls -ls ~/.ssh/*
```

If the permissions are bad then the ssh client won't try to read from it

Comment: 0 drwx------  9 kuba /Users/kuba/.ssh
8 -rwx------  1 kuba /Users/kuba/.ssh/config
looks like I am the owner of all of them

Comment: @Kuba try with ls -la ~/.ssh/

Comment: ls -la ~/.ssh
total 80
drwx------   9 kuba  1029    306 Jul  1 16:33 .
drwx------+ 42 kuba  1029   1428 Jul  1 16:33 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 kuba  1029    406 May  7 14:53 authorized_keys
-rwx------   1 kuba  1029   1528 May 15 13:07 config
-rwx------   1 kuba  1029   1675 May  7 14:53 id_rsa
-rwx------   1 kuba  1029    406 May  7 14:53 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 kuba  1029  16049 May 22 09:36 known_hosts

Comment: @are you sure, you home user dir isn't to open?

Comment: That + over there... isn't that ACLs? That might be the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had the same problem and fixed it by making ssh to create again the `.ssh` folder (just rename `ssh`and execute some ssh command), and copying the needed files afterwards, with the appropriate permissions. (config with 600).

Apparently ssh becomes suspicious if the folder `.ssh` is modified in a way it doesn't approve of...

Comment: Strangely this is the only thing that seemed to improve my situation. ssh suddenly, would *not*, pay any mind to the config in my user account. This the only thing that seemed to wake it up. bonkers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix it by setting the +x flag on my `~/.ssh` dir (0700), while also setting 0600 on `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

SSH won't read the local configuration if it's on an NFS-mounted filesystem. This is worth checking because all the permissions can be just fine and SSH (at least version 6.6) won't give you any indication of why it's not reading the user config. (It will, however, read it from an NFS volume if you use the `-F` option.)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on MacOs. From looking at the debug info of a  manual login (ssh @), I found out that apparently ssh thought that my home directory was `/srv/home/<userid>` and was looking for the `.ssh` directory in there, and ignored the one in `/Users/<userid>/.ssh/`

It's probably got something to do with work setting up the Macs in a specific way, but I'd recommend checking that `ssh` and the Operating System agree on where the home directory is ;)

Answer (score 0):

As 'kasperd' indicated in his comment on the question, note that `ssh` will not necessarily look for '${HOME}/.ssh/config'.  As was found out, it is important to dig deeper and learn where the home directory was at the time of logon and before a new HOME was asserted.

The hint to look through the output of `ssh -xvvvF ~/.ssh/config server` was very insightful in helping answer this very same question.  Upon finding oneself on a system where two different user names have the same UID in the '/etc/passwd' file, this problem was encountered.  The two users have different HOME directories set in '/etc/passwd'.

In such a scenario, it turns out that if one is logged in as the second user with a duplicate UID in the '/etc/passwd' file, `ssh` uses the home directory of the first user's with a matching UID of the user running the SSH command.

Granted, this use case is pretty weird, and will not help for most folk, but it actually did happen, and this Q/A helped resolve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by file permission settings.

Check your `.ssh` dir and files permissions, also check your home dir permission settings.

For me, I don't want others to see my personal files, so I remove `x` permission of my homes dir. Which leads ssh to find authorized keys to the wrong path.

One way to fix this was to set another authority path in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`,for example:

> AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys

then copy your pub to `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys`, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing what @tike said in his comment...

I'm using Kubuntu 20.1 and I've needed to add an include into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, pointing to my config placed into `~/.ssh/` folder too, doing something like this:

```sh
# Include my own configs
Include /home/test/.ssh/.config
```